# При получении названий столбцов таблицы они идут не в том порядке, в котором идут в самой таблице (Laravel 5.8)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

друзья!

Помогите, пожалуйста, с таким вопросом (Laravel 5.8).

Есть таблица в БД. Вот в **таком порядке** расположены столбцы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне нужно получить имена всех столбцов из этой таблицы.

Делаю я это простым запросом:

```
Schema::getColumnListing('my_table_name')
```

В результате получаю такой массив (поля с датами я скрыл в модели, поэтому их нет)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, **порядок** расположения столбцов в массиве не такой как в таблице.

Подскажите, пожалуйста:

1. почему так происходит;
2. по какому принципу происходит сортировка;
3. как это исправить красиво (можно, конечно, сделать `DB::select('show columns from...')`, тогда все в порядке, но придется перебирать результат в цикле и вычленять из объектов имя поля).

Comment: Судя по красивой картинке `getColumnListing` по алфавиту сортирует.

Comment: Да, действительно, по алфавиту, что-то туплю)

Comment: Вроде для `getColumnListing` этот запрос ['select column_name as `column_name` from information_schema.columns where table_schema = ? and table_name = ?'](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/d528f4541dd2dbbe88010de9d22a31860eab1464/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.php#L44)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Друзья, не знаю что произошло, но я перезапустил OpenServer и все заработало правильно. Все колонки теперь в нужном порядке!
Сложно считать это ответом, но как-то так)